# How to combine sum by same id in sql

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have table like this:

```
ID COUNT
-----------
7  2
7  2
8  3
8  3
9  4
9  4
```

And I want to summarise `COUNT` with same `ID` to have

```
ID COUNT
-----------
7  4
8  6
9  8
```

How to get it in oracle db?

EDIT:
I get my table from pipelined function with this type:

```
TYPE g_item IS RECORD (
    g_id  NUMBER,
    g_count  VARCHAR2(50),
    g_who  VARCHAR2(50)
  );
```

Code to get correct table:

```
SQL> select g_id, sum(g_count)
from (SELECT * from TABLE(my_package.get_items_tab ()))
group by g_id;

 G_ID SUM(G_COUNT)
----- ------------
1                9
6                7
2                7
4                7
5                7
3                7
7                7

7 rows selected.
```

EDIT2:
Oh.. it's my fault, I must group it by g_who, not by g_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, sum(count)
from your_table
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `group by` operation:

```
select id, 
       sum(count) as total_count
from the_table
group by id
order by id;
```

Btw: it's a bad habit to use reserved words (`count`) as column names.